# react native scrollView inside Flatlist header can not scroll

Tags: react-native, scrollview, flatlist

based on the requirement, I need to design a ScrollView(vertical) inside FlatList(vertical)

here is my layout

```
<FlatList>
  renderHeader = <ScrollView/>
  renderData= ...
</FlatList>
```

My code run normally, but the scrollView can not scroll, can someone help

Comment: As per my understanding you want to scroll individual renderElement of the `Flatlist`, is it so?

Comment: fix height of each `renderItem` and wrap this component in `ScrollView` will work.

Comment: I want to scroll the scrollview inside header of flatlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem only in android.
add nativeScrollEnabled prop to ScrollView.